# How would one alternately add 2 characters into a string in python?

Tags: python, string, math, join

Like, for example, I have the string '12345' and the string '+*' and I want to make it so that the new string would be '1+2*3+4*5', alternating between the two characters in the second string. I know how to do it with one character using join(), but I just can't figure out how to do it with both alternating. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to forever alternate between the characters:

```
from itertools import cycle 

result = ''.join([c for pair in zip(inputstring, cycle('+*')) for c in pair])[:-1]
```

You do need to remove that last `+` added on, but this does work just fine otherwise:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> inputstring = '12345'
>>> ''.join([c for pair in zip(inputstring, cycle('+*')) for c in pair])[:-1]
'1+2*3+4*5'
```

Comment: This leaves a trailing `+`, which I don't think OP wants

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: that's easily fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

s = '12345'
op = '+*'
answer = ''.join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(s, itertools.cycle(op))))[:-1]
print(answer)
```

Output:

```
1+2*3+4*5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code:

```
string = "12345"
separator = "+*"
result = ""

for i, c in enumerate(string): //enumerate returns a list of tuples [index, character]
  t = i, c  
  result += t[1] //append character
  if(t[0]==len(string)-1): //if reached max length
     break
  if(t[0]%2==0):  //if even
    result += separator[0] //append +
  else:
    result += separator[1] //append *

print(result) //otuput "1+2*3+4*5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Following works without having to trim the end.

```
''.join(map(lambda x: x[0] + x[1],izip_longest('12345',''.join(repeat('*+',len('12345')/2)),fillvalue='')))
```

From python documentation;

> **itertools.izip_longest(*iterables[, fillvalue])**: Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables. If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in with fillvalue. Iteration continues until the longest iterable is exhausted.

Comment: You have the variable `a`.  Is that the original list `12345`?